# Neo4J releationship between existing nodes from CSV

Tags: neo4j

Lets say I have two types of nodes A and B and want to create a relationship between these using a CSV for creating the nodes as well as the relationship.

Nodes A (with header):

```
value
A1
A2
A3
```

Nodes B (with header):

```
id
B1
B2
B3
```

And the many-two-many relationship A2B (with header):

```
value, id
A1, B1
A1, B2
A2, B2
A3, B1
A3, B3
```

I create the nodes with

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///.../a.csv' AS row
MERGE (a:A {value: row.value});
```

and

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///.../b.csv' AS row
MERGE (b:B {id: row.id});
```

But I cannot create the relationship between the nodes. I've for example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///.../a2b.csv' AS row
MATCH (a:A {value: row.value})
MATCH (b:B {id: row.id})
MERGE (a)-[:A2B]->(b);
```

But no relationships are created.

Comment: This is SQL, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>These is a bug in your import queries.

You have used `value` attribute while importing `b.csv`.</strike>

MERGE (b:B {**value**: row.id});

But then used `id` attribute while importing `a2b.csv`.

MATCH (b:B {**id**: row.id})

*Above remark was on the original question.*

**Working solution:**

I had to remove spaces in `a2b.csv`:

```
value,id
A1,B1
A1,B2
A2,B2
A3,B1
A3,B3
```

Cypher queries used:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///csv/a.csv' AS row MERGE (a:A {value: row.value});
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///csv/b.csv' AS row MERGE (b:B {value: row.id});
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///csv/a2b.csv' AS row MATCH (a:A {value: row.value}), (b:B {value: row.id}) CREATE (a)-[:A2B]->(b);
```

[image: RESULT Neo4j]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vihang! When I run your queries I still don't get any relations. I cannot see why. I get ```(no changes, no records)``` as query response.

Comment: Did you tried with the spaces removed in `a2b.csv`?

Comment: Ah, it was, like you also said, the extra space in the a2b that needed to be removed. Thanks a lot Vihang. It works now.

Comment: Also, I made sure that there are no extra spaces at the end.  
Otherwise, MATCH does not happen.

Also, CSV files had empty newline as the last line.